# No viable overloaded operator[] for type 'map<std::__1::string, vector<std::__1::string> >

Tags: c++, vector, maps, operator-overloading

I don't even know what this means I keep getting this error "No viable overloaded operator[] for type 'map >".

error is when I try to print out the map "city_Connection".

```
void travel::get(){
    vector<string>main_cities;
    vector<string>neighbouring_cities;
    map<string, vector<string>>;
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int m;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        string city; cin>>city;
        main_cities.push_back(city);
        cin>>m;
        for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
            string ncity; cin>>ncity;
            neighbouring_cities.push_back(ncity);
        }
        city_Connenction[city]=neighbouring_cities;
        neighbouring_cities.clear();
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cin>>source;
    cin>>destn;
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<city_Connenction['A'];
}
```

Comment: Without a [mcve] we have to guess the types and the location of the error.

Answer (score 0):

In `c++` `'A'` has type `char` and `"A"` has type `const char*`.
The later is convertible to `std::string`, the first one is not.

Use `city_Connenction["A"]`.

Comment: @AniketVishwakarma Yes it does. [live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/E1gRkO6QlBfMAqhj)